# Kubernetes dashboard deployment YAML file link is broken

Tags: kubernetes

Below two URl's are given in GitHub and both are giving 404 Error.
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/master/src/deploy/recommended/kubernetes-dashboard.yaml to https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/master/aio/deploy/recommended/kubernetes-dashboard.yaml

Comment: Where exactly did you find these broken links ?

Answer (score 3):

In Many documentation this broken link is there, correct one is updated in github repo
https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard

try this will work
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/v1.10.1/src/deploy/recommended/kubernetes-dashboard.yaml